# Apache setting up multiple sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, http, ubuntu

I am trying to setup apache to host two domains on this one server, I have created entries for each site in my config as below. Each site runs and points to its own folder and works correctly, however if I run a dev rails app on a non standard port, I find that I am able to view it from either site, once I put the port in. Is this how it should be? How can I explicitly host only the site and not allow users to access the other sites on the non standard ports?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/user/site1/"
ServerName site1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/user/site2/"
ServerName site2
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start a dev server (rails s), then any request which goes to your IP address, with that port, will be sent to that instance.

To only allow access to your apache server, you need to look at your firewall settings (usually on a router, or proxy server if you use one) and only allow incoming requests to port 80 (the standard HTML port). If you want to use your machine via SSH from elsewhere, you might want to open port 22 for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have a few different things running on my vps - bittorrent sync for personal file backup, proxy gui server and some others. I access these all on different ports as well. If I wanted to host websites with different domain names on this box, I would not be able to block access to them being accessed by just using a different port ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can select the ports which are externally available from your router, but you can not stop these ports being accessed by any URL which directs to your IP address. So if I run 'www.toysforcows.com' on my home computer, port 3000 is open and I have a development instance open, I can not stop it being accessed with 'www.toysforcows.com:3000'. But I could close port 3000 to external access. As a rule, any software, fileshares etc. which can be seen externally should be secured.